# error if path to includes non latin characters

Tags: raku

OS: windows 10
Perl6: This is Rakudo Star version 2018.04.1 built on MoarVM version 2018.04.1
implementing Perl 6.c.

Example:

```
perl6 C:\Users\quest\Desktop\example.pl
# sucess

perl6 "C:\Users\quest\Desktop\яп\Perl 6\web-scraping\request.pl"
# Could not open C:\Users\quest\Desktop\╤П╨┐\Perl 6\web-scraping\request.pl. Failed to open file C:\Users\quest\Desktop\╤П╨┐\Perl 6\web-scraping\request.pl: No such file or directory
```

Python 3 example:

```
py "C:\Users\quest\Desktop\яп\py\3\timetest.py"
# sucess
```

Comment: What is the locale?

Comment: russian - Русский (Россия)

Comment: it works: Win + R -> Control -> Часы и регион -> Региональные стандарты -> Дополнительно -> Изменить язык системы -> Использовать юникод (UTF-8)

Comment: cf https://www.nu42.com/2017/02/unicode-windows-command-line.html

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: cmd.exe windows 10

Answer (score 5):

As you have realized, Windows 10 supports UTF-8 for non-Unicode (ie non-UTF-16) apps ([according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_in_Microsoft_Windows#UTF-8), this feature was added with build 17035, released in April 2018, and is still marked 'beta'). This makes Rakudo happy.

However, not respecting your locale while Python manages to do so still seems worthy of a [bug report](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues) to me.

Comment: @raiph, It's Microsoft making up their own definitions. The Windows API functions that accept or return strings come in two flavours: ANSI and Unicode.  The ANSI calls (e.g. `CreateFileA`) accept/return strings encoded using the user's Active Code Page (usually 1252 on US machines), while the UNICODE calls (e.g. `CreateFileW`) accept/return UTF-16le.  tl,dr: In the Microsoft world, Unicode means UTF-16le.

Comment: @raiph Wait, Christoph didn't say UTF-16le isn't Unicode. Quite the opposite. // I don't have `rakudo`

Comment: "(ie non-UTF-16)" -> "(where Unicode is what Microsoft calls UTF-16le)"